# What does のも mean in 仕事が忙しすぎるのも考えものだけど、時間が余るのもなぁ?

Tags: translation

In the following sentence

> 仕事が忙しすぎるのも考えものだけど、時間が余るのもなぁ

what does のも mean?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Put simply, the の after 忙しすぎる and 余る is acting to convert those verbs to nouns, and the も is acting in the sense of "also" (like in クッキーも食べたい, "I want to eat a cookie too").

こと(事）can also be used to treat a verb as a noun, but it has a more formal ring to me.

I haven't seen the word 考えもの used too often, but here is a guess at translating that sentence.

> I think being too busy isn't ideal, but neither is having too much
>   free time.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it is a combination of the normalizer (の) which changes the previous verb or sentence into a noun phrase and the particle (も) meaning "also" or "too" which is connecting the two following phrases.

1. 仕事が忙しすぎるの (Working being too busy) + も
2. 時間が余るの (Having too much time) + も

Combining the two you get:
"Work being too busy is something to think about, but having too much time is also"